# How do I make this Raspberry Pi box?

Tags: woodworking

[image]I found this gorgeous laser-cut box on Amazon for my Raspberry Pi, and wondered how I could possibly make one of these myself.

Can someone help me?

Comment: One can appreciate the desire to DIY something like the box but to be honest the price shown on Amazon will almost for certain be exceeded just in trying to gather the materials for making your own.

Comment: The price at adafruit will be exceeded sooner

Comment: After checking at adafruit, they have [an interesting image](http://www.adafruit.com/images/large/1486kit_LRG.jpg) if you want to do it yourself. Although, at $20, it hard to resist the call of simply buying it.

Comment: I guess I'd start buy buying a laser.

Answer (score 1):

It's just laminated wood.

- Gather 1/2" thick pine boards of an appropriate width.
- Mark your cuts,  and use a router to cut.
- Glue, stack  and clamp.

Comment: And it's actually laser cut laminated wood, so if you have a local Maker collective, you do the layouts to drive the laser, cut them all out, laminate up and glue with some weight holding it together during set and you have the frame part.

Comment: Look closely. The layers of the enclosure are not glued all together. They are kept separate and then bolted together along with the polycarbonate top and bottom with the four nylon bolts. If it was glued the assembly would have to come with the RasPi already inside.

Answer (score 1):

Google "laser cutting service".  You'll find a plethora of laser cutting services that will cut to your dimensions and deliver.